# pdo::beginTransaction does it lock table?

Tags: php, pdo, locking

Can I use this function instead of 'LOCK TABLES' query?

Example:

```
pdo::beginTransaction(); 

    SELECT id AS last_id FROM t WHERE...
    INSERT INTO t (id,...) VALUES (last_id+1,....)

pdo::commit();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to this is: it depends. The most important resource to help you understand exactly what it does, what it doesn't do and how it works is [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.transactions.php).

For a kick off, it depends whether the underlying driver (MySQL, MSSQL, etc etc) supports transaction functionality at all. If the driver does not support transactions, `pdo::beginTransaction();` will fail and return `FALSE`, and all your queries will be executed immediately. This is not to say that a [`LOCK TABLES`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/lock-tables.html) query would fail - it depends whether the underlying database engine supports it.

In fact, in MySQL at least, `pdo::beginTransaction()` follows the same rules as a [`START TRANSACTION`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/commit.html) statement. It does not lock the table immediately, it simply ensures that that the queries that are part of the transaction follow the rules of [ACID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID).

I won't go into full details of exactly which combinations will work and what they will do because they are covered at length in the documents I linked to, and there is no sense in me writing it all out again.